# PHPUnit stops my Docker container

Tags: docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I am using docker-compose to bring up my containers.

I am then running PHPUnit tests via PhpStorm.
When a test has completed, the container is stopped (Exit 0).

I tried adding `restart: always` to my docker-compose.yml but then the container got stuck restarting.

How can I prevent this container from stopping?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18901 I guess...

Comment: Yes, I spotted that, thanks.Please add as answer, so I can flag as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. In fact it works differently: it simply re-creates container each time.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18901 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**P.S.** From what I see you are aware of that already (I believe it's your ticket): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42514

Answer (score 1):

The way I have got around this, is by creating an extra container, just for running tests against.